# colon inside a regular expression for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ -.''""]+)$/
```

It works perfectly well allowing alphabets, numbers, and some special characters like `-`, `.`, `'` and `"`.

No I want it to allow a colon as well (`:`). I tried the following regex but it fails - it starts allowing many other special characters.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ :-.''""]+)$/
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-` has a special meaning in character classes, just like in `a-z`. Try this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ :\-.'"]+)$/
```

`-.` (space to dot) allows a few extra characters, like `#`, `$` and more. If that was intentional, try:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ -.'":]+)$/
```

Also, know that you don't have to include any character more than once, that's pretty pointless. `'` and `"` appeared twice each, they can safely be removed.

By the way, sing a colon appears *after* the dot in the [character table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_Controls_and_Basic_Latin), that regex isn't valid. It shouldn't allow extra characters, you're suppose to get an error. In Firefox, you get: `invalid range in character class`.

Comment: A more readable alternative might be to move the `-` to the beginning or the end of the character class (which also makes it lose its special meaning).

Comment: @cebewee - well, that depends. I like to escape it anyway, to make sure its meaning is clear, and to prevent errors. Another developer might change `[a-z_-]` to `[a-z_-~]`, and then we have a problem.

Comment: Thank you guys. That worked :).. I did not notice "-." . Thanks again for this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ :.'"-]+)$/
```

I've moved `-` to the end of the character class so that it is treated literally and not as range operator. The same problem exists in your original regex too where `-` is being treated as range operator.

Also I've dropped redundant `'` and `"` from the char class.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is probably wrong to start with. You have `/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ -.''""]+)$/` where you probably mean `/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ \-.''""]+)$/` (note the backslash in front of the dash). The `-` within `[]` indicates a range, so `-.` (space dash dot) means "from a space through to a dot" and if you put the colon in there, it just changes that range.

So adding the colon and escaping the dash (and removing the redundant `'` and `"` near the end), you probably want: `/^([a-zA-Z0-9_ \-.'":]+)$/`